# jQuery img error management in a function

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to log error on server side when an image is not found on client side.
For that I would like to call an ajax function to log the error on server side.

I tried adding onerror on my img tag, but I cannot call a function on onerror (it works fine I just do the error management on onerror itself without calling an other function).

How can I call a function when there is an error loading an image ?

As you can see in this fiddle, only hello 1 and hello 2 are displayed.

hello 3 which is in a function is not displayed  (I have the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: hello3 is not defined")

hello 4 is not displayed either, it seems error function is deprecated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljj68/3/

HTML code:

```
<script>
    function hello2() {
        alert('hello 2');
    }
</script>

<img src='test1.png' onerror='alert("hello 1")'>
<img src='test2.png' onerror='hello2()'>
<img src='test2.png' onerror='hello3()'>
<img id'img_4' src='test2.png'>
```

Javascript code:

```
function hello3() {
    alert('hello 3');
}

$('#img_4').error(function() {
    alert('hello 4');
});
```

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Fixed jsFiddle, you shouldn't wrap in loader method (jsFiddle) and use `.on('error',handler)` syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljj68/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed jsFiddle, you shouldn't wrap in loader method (jsFiddle) and use .on('error',handler) syntax: jsfiddle.net/Ljj68/4
(cf. comment on question, thanks A. Wolff)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `hello3` function before calling it in `onerror`, in the same way you have done for `hello2`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljj68/5/)

Comment: Javscript hoists variable declaration regarding scope. OP's issue was that hello3() in jsFiddle was wrapped in loader method, making it not global

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes. That is why I wrapped it in <script> tag. If jsfiddle's "wrap it in head" would also work, I presume

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but is there any way to implement my function in a separate javascript file ? (I saw it worked fine implementing it in html part as I did with hello2)

Comment: yes. Just put your code in a .js file and reference it in html by `<script src="path to your js"></script>`